# Use IO-Link v1.1 without ISDU

Tags: 3-wire, io-link

I want to use IO-Link v1.1, but my device has no ISDU implementation.

Is it possible to still use v1.1?

The IODD-Checker says:

```
Bit 0 from mSequenceCapability shall match the support from ISDU
```

But after reading the specification, I think I don't have to implement it.

Comment: So you want to build your own IOL device without ISDU, right? In this case you had to put your parameter in the DirectParameterPage2. It is highly recommended not to use DirectParameterPage 2 AND ISDU in the same device. In this case the checker should give you a warning. But in my opinion you are allowed to bulid a device without ISDU. But why should someone do this?

Comment: Thanks for the info. The reason why we are building a device without ISDU is, because our device stack has no ISDU implementation. It would be some work to implement it and we don't need it.